# Dynamics 365 Portals - Employee Self-Service - 'Content Editor Tool' not appearing for 2nd Admin user

Tags: dynamics-365

I have a trial Dynamics 365 Portal for Employee Self-Service. I am also seeing this issue in my real Office 365/Dynamics 365 instance.

For my first Admin user I was able to log into the Portal, add them to the Administrator web role, log in again and see the 'Content Editor Tool' floating in the top right corner. All good.

For a second Admin user I do exactly the same thing... but no 'Content Editor Tool' appears. I have tried to match both the first Admin account and the second Admin account exactly the same but nothing happens.
I have also Restarted the Portal from the Admin center and have turned the Portal off and on again.

Is there anyway I can diagnose why this second Admin is not working?

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out. Web Roles and Security Roles are not the same.

Security Roles are set at User level and provide access to Dynamics 365.

Web Roles are set at Contact level and provide access to the Portal.

For the other Portals you just send an Invitation Workflow, and I still had to do this step even though the User had been created already by virtue of logging into the Employee Self Service (ESS) portal. I created the invite for the Contact, saved it, added the Administrator Web Role, and then selected 'Other Activities' (in the ... button) and then 'Invite Redemption'.

In the 'Invite Redemption' dialog, select the Contact again, provide any username, and click the 'Save' button.

This will complete the workflow to add the Web Role. Next time you log in as that user the tool will be visible.